# safari ios ( iPad ) - custom font not working on javascript generated text

Tags: javascript, ios, webfonts

I'm trying to use a webfont on javascript generated text.

It works on every desktop browser.

For iOS it works for the text that is already in page, but strangely it does not work for the text added via javascript.

It seems to me that this is a specific iOS issue, but i couldn't find any advice about it, so i'm wondering if someone knows about it.

I declared the font-family on body tag

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are adding additional elements into the text container and there are no matching selectors in your CSS.

Or you can try to assign the font property to the star selector:

```
* {
    font: /* your font-definitions go here */
}
```

Comment: Edited original question, i declared the font-family for the body tag